# Send batch emails from terminal with attachments

Tags: terminal, email, catalina

I would like to write a bash script that does the following:

1. Read from an excel file a column of email addresses
2. For each email address (say person1@wherever) attach an associated file (say person1.xlsx) and send email with standard body.

In parts I have most of what I need except the mail bit doesn't seem to work for me. I tried the following:

```
echo "hello world" | mail -s "test email" geoff@here.com
```

Yet the email doesn't arrive. In the terminal under `mail` I see:

```
N  1 MAILER-DAEMON@Name  Sat Jun 27 12:02  72/2630  "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"
```

I have Mac OSX Catalina.

Comment: What does the MAILER-DAEMON say? Have you set up SMTP for the `mail` CLI command? If you don't use a third party SMTP server (e.g. Gmail), the system will (AFAIR) look up the MX record of the recipient domain, then try to contact that SMTP server directly - and if you do that, the SMTP server will usually rate the mail as "highly likely spam". Hope these questions help nudge you along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## curl

You can bypass setting up `mail` and use [`curl`](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-smtp) to talk directly to your SMTP server. See [using curl to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722556/using-curl-to-send-email) for more details:

```sh
curl --ssl-reqd \
  --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' \
  --user 'username@gmail.com:password' \
  --mail-from 'username@gmail.com' \
  --mail-rcpt 'john@example.com' \
  --upload-file mail.txt
```

*mail.txt* file contents:

```
From: "User Name" <username@gmail.com>
To: "John Smith" <john@example.com>
Subject: This is a test

Hi John,
I’m sending this mail with curl thru my gmail account.
Bye!
```

To attach a file, see the link recommended by [lhs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22769/lhf), [curl : send html email with embedded image and attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728855/curl-send-html-email-with-embedded-image-and-attachment).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Before I try the above, is there a security issue in giving ones email password in such a command?

Comment: I see `--upload-file mail.txt` handles the body of the email, but this answer doesn't address point two, attaching a separate file to the email. Is this doable with `curl`?

Comment: So I tried this and I get the following response `curl: (67) Login denied`

Comment: Wow, I got this working! I needed to do in gmail whatever it was that receives the following "Access for less secure apps has been turned on". Magically, it then seems to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Geoff, You said you got this working, but does that include the attachment of your .xlsx file too, and if so, what did you have to add to the command for that to happen?

Comment: @user3439894 Once I've got it all together I'll post what I have here.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728855/curl-send-html-email-with-embedded-image-and-attachment